# Machine Learning location neighbour relations

Tags: machine-learning

I have a machine learning project related to estimating the prices of houses. The data includes houses located at locations A B C D E F G. Suppose there is no house at location A in the training data, but there is a house at location A in production that needs to be estimated. The location data is the most important parameter for the model because in some locations the houses are expensive, while in others they are cheap.

Now, because there is no house in location A in the training data, the model estimates this house incorrectly in production. But there are houses similar to this house in B C D or other regions that are neighbors of location A.

Now I want to make this If there are no houses in Area A, I want to look at the neighboring locations and make a close estimation. I have such an idea, but do you have an idea how I can give it at the ML level?

[image]

Comment: How about data augmentation (i.e. creating snythetic data) or knn-imputation?

Comment: Is it the distict which is a good indicator for the price level, or is it the other features, which are associated with the distict?
My thinking is: How would you know, if A is a cheap or expensive district, if you don't have any data?